# Angular value in input bound to model variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I need help spotting the problem in my code. Angular.js is binding input *values* with *ng-model* for me, which is not what I want.
I have an angular repeater with an ng-include like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
  <label>{{item.number}}</label>
  <div ng-include='item.template'></div>
</div>
```

The included item template is a simple input field, based in item.template. The problematic tags are <textarea> and <input> for me.

Ie I include this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.number" />
```

The item looks like:

```
{
  number: 1
  , template: 'text'
  , text: 'Some text'
  , value: 'Some value'
}
```

So when the thing above renders, I get

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.number" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

But the problem is that in my input field, I have the item number as the *value*, and if I change the value, my label also gets changed. Even if I put **value=""** or **placeholder="blah"**, I still get this behavior.

I haven't gotten that far yet, but I suppose the model is also updated with the number.

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: this is what is expected its a 2 way data binding

Comment: @Atrix1987 Thanks, that was it :) I should probably put "name"=item.number" and bind the ng-model to something extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously, {{item.number}} is bound to your item object (two way binding FTW! :-) ). If you want that label to be set upon rendering and remain unchanged, then in your controller you should create another field in each item called 'originalNumber', and bind your labels to that field.

Comment: Nah, basically what I needed was input name="item.number" ng-model="something else to get a hook on"

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to keep the field editable, but have an immutable label (populated with the original value of the field).

Answer (score 4):

Angular creates two way binding between model and input elements when `ng-model` is used. Any changes to the model update the input element (The default behavior for all bindings) and any change done in UI input element updates the model.

To get rid of this behavior you can

```
<input type="text" value='{{item.number}}' class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
```